# Issue with creating pipes between links in navigation

Tags: html, css

I need to create and center pipes `|` between links in navigation. I'm currently struggling with centering them. I've made this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ppqq6Lj3/ :

```
.header-links {
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.header-links li {
    float:left;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.header-links li:first-child {
    padding-left:0px;
}
.header-links li:last-child {
    padding-right:10px;
}
.header-links li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.header-links li a:hover {
    color:#313131;
}
.header-links li + li::before {
    content:" | ";
}

ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

How I can center the pipes between the links? Additionally, how I can change pipe color?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play with position:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/tLjw5cLd/2/

```
.header-links li {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.header-links li + li::before {
    content:"|";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. I will keep the snippet in mind :)

Comment: No worries, I would do it already but I need to wait 4 minutes before doing it :)